# "No architectures" error when compiling objective flickr for iphone device

Tags: iphone, architecture, flickr

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to compile my XCode project to debug on my device.

```
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).
```

I've included ObjectiveFlickr in my project just as the readme describes. I've gone through the process several times and redownloaded objectiveFlickr a few times to start over.

I've gotten objectiveFlickr to work on devices in the past. I don't know why I am suddenly having trouble. Can anybody point me to something that might hold the clue I need? Any other info I need to provide? I made only changes to my project that are specified by the OF documentation.

I also get this error when compiling the included snap-n-run example project provided with OF. So I must be missing something beneath my project.

Thanks,

- Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post for another solution. I have not tested it for release/dist but it works for debug so far.
http://groups.google.com/group/objectiveflickr/browse_thread/thread/ad8e5ec6ba976672

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't able to truly solve this problem. However, after corresponding with Lukhanos, the creator of objflickr, I tried including the objflickr source code directly in my project. After a bit of trial and error to sort out which source files were needed (the "source" directory and the "LFWebAPIKit" directory) and adding the "SystemConfiguration" framework to my project, things are building OK.

Still no clue as to why I was experiencing this issue, but at least I can get my project built now!

Thanks
 - Charlie